# Posting to friends facebook WITHOUT using Graph API - Python

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, python-2.7

I know that using Graph API we can no longer post on a friends wall. Has anyone else found a way around it? I have my current application setup with access tokens and what not - but because Facebook graph API can no longer post to a friends wall using the friends profile ID, I am kinda lost on how to fix this. Is there a way around it? using Python?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) instead.  See [here](http://yougapi.com/2013/03/why-facebook-removed-the-ability-to-post-on-friends-walls-via-graph-api/) for the reasons why.

Comment: Can you maybe provide me a sample/psuedo code to implement this with python?